# C/C++: with int i[3], why i[2] is the same as 2[i]?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I just know this trick.

In C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i[3]={5,7,11};
    cout << 2[i];
    return 0;
}
```

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{  
    int i[3]={5,7,11};
    printf("%d", 2[i]);
    return 0; 
}
```

yes, these are allowed, both output are 11.

why i[2] can be expressed as 2[i]?

Comment: http://madebyevan.com/obscure-cpp-features/#what-square-brackets-really-mean

Comment: Mostly because arrays in C/C++ aren't "real" but are just a different way to deal with pointers.

Comment: (And this is a dupe, but I'm too lazy to look it up.)

Comment: Well, this is something I didn't know :) Everyday you learn something new.

Comment: @HotLicks That's not true. Arrays are 100% real. They're just treated differently to other objects (they decay to pointers and aren't copyable).

Comment: While this may be something you don't know, it is also something you don't _need_ to know...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a[i] = i[a]

*(a+i) = *(i+a)
```

Hence both are same and is valid.