# Access the array element in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I came across a different way of accessing an array element today. I am just curious if its correct way to access an array element.

Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[4] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
    printf ("---> %d \n", 2[arr]);
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the output,

```
---> 6
```

I thought the program will not compile but it did! I tried to compile it on Linux and Windows and it works fine on both. Expert views on this?

Comment: `i[arr] == arr[i]` because `*(arr + i) == *(i + arr)`.

Comment: [Array subscripting is commutative in C](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228793/c-c-with-int-i3-why-i2-is-the-same-as-2i/27228808#27228808

Answer (score 3):

This works because for the expression `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, which implies that you can swap the order of `a` and `b`, the addition doesn't care.